# I can't open another person's react project?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to run a react app on my local host, It is a project that wasn't created on my machine. I am getting these errors !

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\package.json'
  npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. 
   npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Abdullah Ch\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02- 
03T19_49_57_690Z-debug.log
```

Comment: You need to go to the project directory before running npm start. Also, make sure you run npm install first.

Answer (score 1):

cd into the project folder (via command line) -> npm install -> npm start

Answer (score -1):

First, it can be because of different version of Node and npm.
Please use same version with the host that app was created.

If it doesn't work, please remove node_modules directory and run command 'npm install'. After that run command 'npm start'.
Please do these with stable versions of Node and npm.

Perhaps it will work.